# GIT Renaming folder history

Tags: git

I have 2 different repos (`RepoA`, `RepoB`), where one is treating the other as a base project, so that `RepoA` is a remote to `RepoB`.

The problem is that there is a folder that was in `RepoA` that is named `utils`, and `RepoB` pulled from the the remote `RepoA`. So at this point both repos have a folder named `utils`.

Now the problem is whenever I change anything in the `utils` folder in `RepoA` and pull at `RepoB` the changes previously done in the `utils` folder at `RepoA` change the `utils` folder in `RepoB`. I would like to keep the `utils` folder in `RepoB` untouched from any merges.

I tried renaming the `utils` folder to `utils_base` in `RepoA` but it is still applying changes to `RepoB`. I don't mind having 2 `utils` folders in this case at `RepoB` (`utils` and `utils_base`). I only care about perserving the `utils` folder in `RepoB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried renaming the `utils` folder to `utils_base` in RepoA but it is still applying changes to RepoB.

It is possible `repoB` considered repoA `utils_base` as `utils` renamed, wich means any pull from `repoA` update files from `repoB` `utils`, when `repoA/main` is merged to repoB `main` branch.

I would also rename `utils` to `utils_base` in `repoB`, and commit, making sure both repos are in sync.

Then, on the next commit, I would recreate in `repoB` the `utils` folder, with its own content.

From there, any pull from `repoA` should not impact `utils` in `repoB`